# image not refreshing with kinaticjs after ajax call(Firefox,opera)

Tags: jquery, kineticjs

I stuck with issue that image is dynamically changes via ajax on shape object using setFillPattern(With same file name and location but dynamically changing on server) function but in Firefox and safari it wont work.

Open URL given below in Chrome as well as Firefox you will get better idea of this issue.

http://ringinghost.com/shutter/

In Firefox,Opera,IE image changes only once(First time) when changing value of subsequent drop downs and work fine in chrome and safari(it might be layout engine problem or so).

Here is JS file where change event fires for drop-downs.

http://ringinghost.com/shutter/js/events.js

Note : I already checked with disabling cache on browsers but it wont work.

Thanks for your time and consideration in advancce.

-Naitik

Comment: are u using the same name for the image...if so how are u setting the image src ?? Pls post the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that problem in catching. You are using same url. I think you must use other way, because currently changing image will affect ALL users. You can see at network tab that firefox is not doing new requests for images. (but chrome do). So problem not in kinetic.

Comment: Hi Lavrton,

Thanks for helping me but jquery or kinaticJS provides any sync option for this isuue?

-Naitik